# ASP.NET MVC initialize Controller and call action programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a scheduled jobs controller - these jobs will call a **Controller** and an **Action** capturing the result.  I would rather have all this happen on the backend and not involve http calls.

Its kind of like what happens with Unit testing - for instance:

```
var controller = new TestController();
var result = controller.Index("TestParameter") as ViewResult;
```

The issue is in this example the controller and action are not dynamic, does anyone know how to initialize a controller and call an action with the name of the controller and action as string paramater? Such as -

```
public ActionResult run(string controllerName, string actionName)
{
    var controller = new Controller(controllerName);
    var result = controller.action(actionName).("TestParameter") as ViewResult;
    return Content(result);
}
```

Comment: A controller's purpose is to handle browser requests.  Are you calling an MVC controller from another class?

Comment: Yes I want to call many controllers and actions from another single controller action such as the run action above.

Comment: The only thing that should be calling an MVC controller is the browser.

Comment: So what you're saying is if I have a large mvc application and I want to call multiple actions in different controllers from one controller dynamically this is not following protocol?  I am trying to figure out the best way to dynamically call these code in these actions with 1 call instead of individually with windows scheduled tasks.  I would rather handle this all on the backend and the code is already in the controllers, but they will still need to be web accessible.

Comment: Your controller action handles a browser event.  If you need your controller to execute something during that action, call another non-controller class.  You should probably read up on MVC.

Comment: I hear you - but this is the easiest and most maintainable route to my solution.

Comment: Oh well if it's the easiest solution. By all means, ignore how the MVC framework is designed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `ControllerFactory` along with the `ActionDescriptor` to dynamically execute the action:

```
public ActionResult Run(string controllerName, string actionName)
{
    // get the controller
    var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    var ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(this.Request.RequestContext, controllerName) as Controller;
    var ctrlContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext, ctrl);
    var ctrlDesc = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(ctrl.GetType());

    // get the action
    var actionDesc = ctrlDesc.FindAction(ctrlContext, actionName);

    // execute
    var result = actionDesc.Execute(ctrlContext, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "parameterName", "TestParameter" }
    }) as ActionResult;

    // return the other action result as the current action result
    return result;
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: I'd like to say, from the code above, I was able to build the Scheduled Jobs functionality into my application, and it has been running like a charm for many a months :)  We can on the fly schedule any action to run on schedule, I think though thats not the way MVC was designed, this is a great solution.  Cheers @haim770!

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure where is your real problem lies—do you want to test **controller/action** or do you want to test functionality of your jobs?

1. If you need to test **controller/action** it would involve `HttpContext`.
2. If you need to test your job functionality better way to separate that in your **service / repository layer** and you can do testing with using repository pattern.