# MVC Controller inside ApiController with ControllerContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, razor

Short story about what I am doing and why. I had been doing view to string conversion in Mvc project, but suddenly all project moved to the REST API. But I had to use razor engine to convert my view with all model data there, so I was trying to use directly from api, but it didn't work for me, so I decided to create a Mvc controller and call it directly from API, what is missing, only ControllerContext, because when I create controller directly, it appears to be null.

Here is my Api controller

```
public class AttachmentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(long id)
    {
        try
        {
            var mvcController = new AttachmentMvcController();

            var result = await mvcController.Get();

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Mvc Controller

```
public class AttachmentMvcController : Controller
{
    public AttachmentMvcController(){ }

    public async Task<byte[]> Get()
    {
        string result;

       // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // HERE IS MY PROBLEM, I NEED this.ControllerContext, but it is null !!!
        if (ControllerContext == null)
        {
            // create it and do task 
            var factory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IControllerFactory>() ?? new DefaultControllerFactory();
            AttachmentMvcController controller = factory.CreateController(ctx.RequestContext, "AttachmentMvc") as AttachmentMvcController;

            RouteData route = new RouteData();
            route.Values.Add("action", "ActionThatUsesControllerContext"); // ActionName, but it not required

            ControllerContext newContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controller);
            controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
            result = await controller.ActionThatUsesControllerContext(id);
        }
        else
        {
            result = await this.ActionThatUsesControllerContext(id);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> ActionThatUsesControllerContext()
    {
        {....}
        // here I am trying to use helper that uses that controller context
        string viewAsString = ControllerContext.RenderPartialToString("MyView", requestModel);
        {....}
    }
}
```

If anyone has idea how to get that ControllerContext or any other ways to get my razor engine render view inside ApiController, please share.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31388529/1625737 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28968026/1625737

Comment: Thanks for comment, actually I did workaround without calling an api, I call directly to Mvc and that's all, I was trying to use both methods ealier, none of them seemed to work when creating Mvc Controller inside ApiController directly. Difference between request types, controllercontext types on controllers confused me so I had no options and time to spend trying to somehow cast between them. :)